# How to make the excerpt in WordPress search results show the piece of text containing the found words?

Tags: wordpress

By default WordPress shows in search results the headers of the found pages and **the beginning of the page content** in the excerpt.

Is it possible to modify the excerpt in search results so that it would show **not the beginning** of content, but a piece of text **where the searched words are found**?

As an example: say, we have the following page found by search:

> - Header
> - 1 paragraph
> - 2 paragraph
> - **3 paragraph - containing the searched words**
> - 4 paragraph

By default it will be shown in search results as:

> - Header
> - 1 paragraph

And i want it this way:

> - Header
> - **3 paragraph - containing the searched words**

Is it possible, and if yes, how?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will have create yours search.php file.
You need to include the Wordpress loop in your search.php template to loop through the search results and show them as part of the template(get_template_part( 'content', 'search' )).
In template you can show all what you want. For example use preg_match function to find your search text in page and display only it

```
    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'shape' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
    </section><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

Comment: This relies specifically on the 'template_part' of search template. Is hardly the answer to the question.